# Illustrator wont export random layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, export

Although layers are visible, some are not exporting. There seems to be no consistency with this, from artboard to artboard.

[image]
[image]

In this case, I cannot see "mBTC" or "VIRES IN NUMERIS"
I'm totally stumped.

Here is a download of the project, I apologize for the size http://ge.tt/7My7izf1/v/0

Comment: Make certain nothing is set to Overprint, and you **do not** have overprint preview on.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out thanks to [Why can I only see a path when it's not white?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/why-can-i-only-see-a-path-when-its-not-white)

Although my solution was a bit different since I didn't have "Simulate Colored Paper" on.

(1) Turn overprint preview on (View > Overprint Preview). This will at least let you see what is and is not showing
(2) Add to your panels the Object Properties pane
(3) Click on the objects that do not appear
(4) Unclick "Overprint Fill"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be just a work around, but moving all your elements out of the clipping path [that Illustrator tends to create], in the layers palette, enabled me to 'save for web' with all elements visible.

[image]

Comment: I think this may be the answer: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/why-can-i-only-see-a-path-when-its-not-white